# How and should I invalidate the jwt token Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I've seen this as part of an asnwer in stackoverflow:

> There isn't any need to store JWTs on the server side. That is the
> whole point as JWTs enable "asynchronous" token verification on the
> server side.

Here is what I have, auth/authorization microservice and resources microservices, login generated token send to client, client use the token for resource microservice calls (no call to the DB or even network call to auth - all what you need is in the token) where refresh token request is happen every hour (acceess token expiration).

Now, I've implemented two new end points.

1. Delete user by admin.
2. Upgrade user role to admin.

In both cases, the changes won't take into account till the next refresh token request (DB call).
So I found myself all of sudden creatign new table for session key user id and token (cause user can have two browser where he might wish to log out in one of them only). And, I have now ConcurrentMap to store the loggen on status. Blacklisting is the main feature. But, all microservices need access to it. So, again, all the purpose of jwt is to avoid call to auth for each request within the session (refresh token expiry).

How to deal with this conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the statelessness of JWT tokens is both their main advantage and disadvantage. By default, there is no way to invalidate a JWT token using just the tokens alone.

However, there are certainly workarounds for invalidating users authenticated by JWT tokens. All of them have their pros and cons, and it all depends on your needs.

## Using Event-Driven Architecture and Local Caching (a.k.a. 'Push Model')

If you don’t mind that information about token invalidation may be inconsistent across microservices for a short time, you may use events to inform microservices about tokens that should be invalidated. So, after adding a user to the blacklist or granting them additional privileges, etc., the information gets propagated across all the microservices. Then, a microservice checks its in-memory cache to determine if that token should be invalidated. If it should, it responds accordingly to the client, who should then try to obtain a new token.

In this approach, you don't need to call the database (or make any network call) after each request. All you need is to check the local cache. This is a 'push model' of propagating information across microservices about token invalidation. This is beneficial when you don't want to bear the overhead of invalidation checks during the request, but you don’t mind the overhead during the token invalidation process, and you don’t mind denormalizing this information across all the microservices.

## Using Fast Cache (a.k.a. 'Pull Model')

Essentially, this is the same model as you described, but instead of using a database, perhaps using a fast, external cache like Redis may help? So, every time a request with a JWT token is made, you need to check whether the token for the selected user was invalidated. If it was, you respond with information that the user should refresh their token. If it turns out that the number of queries to the external cache (let's say Redis) is too large, then maybe a hybrid model could help. For example, using the @Cacheable annotation with local in-memory cache and a short invalidation time for that cache may be beneficial.

This all relates to the CAP theorem. If you want to have high availability, you must sacrifice some consistency.

## Using Short-Lived JWT Tokens and Long-Lived Refresh Tokens

If you don’t have very heavy traffic and can afford more frequent JWT token refresh calls, then perhaps just shortening the lifespan of a JWT token to a few minutes would make sense for you? This is also a very common and simple approach to dealing with blacklisting and revalidating JWT tokens. Of course, it does not fix the core problem - you still need to wait (at most) the time the JWT token is valid for changes to take effect. But in many scenarios, those few minutes may be acceptable.

Comment: Great and comprehensive answer! Let me share, ShortLive it's not accetable, on expiry my client make requests after refresh (retry). refresh token is longlive by definition but access token need to be in hour(s) mark. As for your the first 2 choises, I think that saving the webclient call for each request (the plan was cache and not DB) is the key part that I took from you.

Comment: Now, the first option look promising, I;m using kafka, there is no issue for me to send message where everyonoe can consume. There will be copy paste for this mechanism across all microservices. However, if we are using only cache,  on deplument and/or startup there will empty map. can you see an issue here cause this approach is more preferred

Comment: If you're interested in implementing the 'push model' (the 'first option'), then you are right - the edge case here is filling the local cache at startup. I intentionally didn't mention it earlier, as I'm not familiar with your architecture. The are also few ways you can get around it. I believe the simplest solution is to maintain a copy of the cache elsewhere (perhaps in another microservice, an external cache, or a database) and retrieve it during service startup.